# Замена пути ссылки при клике

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Помогите пожалуйста решить такую проблему.

Вот тут на страничке товара когда кликаешь по фотографиям что слева они подставляются в большую, хочу сделать лупу при наведении на большое фото

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лупу я поставил, но при переходе на другие фото и при наведении увеличивает оно только фото что изначально было большим, не знаю как осуществить чтобы при переходе на новое фото увеличивалось именно то фото на которое нажали.

Сам скрипт лупы работает таким образом что в ссылке href ставится фото для увеличения, при переходе на другие фото у меня заменяется в img путь, а надо сделать чтобы также заменялось и в href

```css
.prev li {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
}

img{ 
 border: none
}
h1{
 margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}.cloud-zoom{
 width: 200px;
}
.cloud-zoom-lens {
 border: 4px solid #888;
 margin: -4px;
 background-color: #fff; 
 cursor: move;  
}
.cloud-zoom-title {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 position: absolute !important;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 3px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center; 
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 10px;
}
.cloud-zoom-big {
 border: 4px solid #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.cloud-zoom-loading {
 background:#222;
 padding:3px;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://testing5543.mcdir.ru/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://testing5543.mcdir.ru/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js"></script>
  

<ul>
  <div class="prev">
     <li>
    <img class="hover-image" src="https://undercoverofthenight.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/207530107_rollingstone-comnov12011_122_103lo-1.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('bg1').src=this.src" style="cursor: pointer; width:61px;height:91px;display:block;">
    <img class="hover-image" src="https://img2.goodfon.ru/original/600x1024/5/9c/alisa-devushka-krasivaya-volosy-745.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('bg1').src=this.src" style="cursor: pointer; width:61px;height:91px;display:block;">
    <img class="hover-image" src="https://undercoverofthenight.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/207530107_rollingstone-comnov12011_122_103lo-1.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('bg1').src=this.src" style="cursor: pointer; width:61px;height:91px;display:block;">
     </li>
 </div>
</ul>

<div class="main-img-wrapper main-image-product-1113">
 <a class="main-image zoom-hover lightbox-img-src-1113 nut cloud-zoom" rel="position: 'inside', adjustX: 0, adjustY:0" href="https://undercoverofthenight.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/207530107_rollingstone-comnov12011_122_103lo-1.jpg" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <img id="bg1" class="img-changer-1113 main-img resized" src="https://undercoverofthenight.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/207530107_rollingstone-comnov12011_122_103lo-1.jpg" width="323">
 </a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте назначение атрибута `href` родительского анкера в обработчики `onclick`:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('bg1').src=this.src;document.getElementById('bg1').parentNode.href=this.src"
```

```css
.prev li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="prev">
    <li>
      <img class="hover-image" src="https://undercoverofthenight.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/207530107_rollingstone-comnov12011_122_103lo-1.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('bg1').src=this.src;document.getElementById('bg1').parentNode.href=this.src" style="cursor: pointer; width:61px;height:91px;display:block;">
      <img class="hover-image" src="https://img2.goodfon.ru/original/600x1024/5/9c/alisa-devushka-krasivaya-volosy-745.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('bg1').src=this.src;document.getElementById('bg1').parentNode.href=this.src" style="cursor: pointer; width:61px;height:91px;display:block;">
      <img class="hover-image" src="https://undercoverofthenight.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/207530107_rollingstone-comnov12011_122_103lo-1.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('bg1').src=this.src;document.getElementById('bg1').parentNode.href=this.src" style="cursor: pointer; width:61px;height:91px;display:block;">
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>

<div class="main-img-wrapper main-image-product-1113">
  <a class="main-image zoom-hover lightbox-img-src-1113 nut cloud-zoom" rel="position: 'inside', adjustX: 0, adjustY:0" href="https://undercoverofthenight.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/207530107_rollingstone-comnov12011_122_103lo-1.jpg" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <img id="bg1" class="img-changer-1113 main-img resized" src="https://undercoverofthenight.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/207530107_rollingstone-comnov12011_122_103lo-1.jpg" width="323">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: секунду, сейчас перепроверю

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста добавил код выше, я все достаю из бд, он немного другой, может ошибся когда при смене своего кода на ваш

Comment: @АлексейСоколов было бы хорошо, если бы скрипт лупы Вы тоже включили в вопрос

Comment: а там файлы лупы подключаю что скачал с интернета, как я их сюда могу подключить ? могу я вам скинуть отдельно все файлы ? скачаете и посмотрите в файле article.php строка 105, как все устроено

Comment: @АлексейСоколов Нет, файл не надо. Все работает даже здесь, только нe по наведению, а по клику.

Comment: возможен такой вариант ? а то я уже перерыл столько сайтов, как только не пробовал осуществить, не получается

Comment: проверил, вроде ссылка и правда меняется, но все равно при наведении на главное фото увеличивается фото что было первым

Comment: пробую, не получается сюда лупу подключить

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста отдельным файлом, закинул исходники с бд все сюда 
https://yadi.sk/d/gpHnJxW03X6Vk3
Ссылка и правда меняется, но лупа срабатывает почему то все равно на первой фотографии

Comment: Так это не лупа а просто переход на страницу картинки. По-моему автор просил лупу как на Амазон или Алиэкспресе.